# Change app notification status too Priority programmatically

Tags: android, notifications, scheduling

Android 5.0 added in the new "Priority" setting for notifications interruptions (settings -> sound and notification -> app notifications -> my app)

How do I check if my app has been set as a Priority app?

How can I programmatically set my app as a priority app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no APIs for either of these things through Android 5.1.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare lets hope that we can interact with these soon